# How to make a graphing code graph with csv instead of txt

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code that lets me graph stacked bar charts, and it imports data from a .txt file.

```
df = pd.read_table("tiempo.txt",header =None, names = ['Tiempos no Contributivos','Tiempos Contributivos', 'Tiempos Productivos'])
df['bar'] = 1 
dfgroup = df.groupby('bar').sum()
ax = dfgroup [['Tiempos no Contributivos','Tiempos Contributivos', 'Tiempos Productivos']].plot(kind='bar', title ="Tiempos de obra",
         figsize=(15, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel(" ", fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("Tiempo(segundos)", fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

The graph this code throws, looks like this.
[Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNFYp.png)

What i need is for this code to work like its been working, but instead of reading a .txt file, i need it to read a .csv file.

When i tried to switch the .txt file for the .csv one in the reading part, this happened.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCGw1.png)

The data used in this code looks like this (Wont post the entirety of it because there are like 500 rows)

[Example of the data used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qn6HZ.png)

Comment: Have you tried just referencing a csv file instead of your tiempo.txt? As far as I know csv files are just comma separated text files

Comment: Yup, that's the first thing i tried, and it didnt work. Im going to edit the code to show the error that shows.

Comment: @JuanPabloMejiaRuiz Could I have an example data set that should work? It'd help a lot.

Comment: @nfnneil Is it okay for you if i post a picture of the type of data inside the question?

Comment: We need to see the CSV file itself (plain text), not the spreadsheet version, like `200,160,120` etc. `read.table` should be able to detect the format given the proper file format, or you could try adding `sep=','`  Your error message indicates that it is expecting the header line to be in your data file, but is not finding the column with the header `'Tiempos no Contributivos'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed that and changed the function to `read_csv`.  Then I noticed that your csv wasn't comma delimited, and was, instead, tab delimited.  So, I added `delimiter='\t'` the read. Next, I went ahead adn updated the functions you were calling to set the `ylabel` and `xlabel` to their modern names.  Then, I took your current column names and fed them into the plot, that way we have a properly labeled graph.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("tiempo.txt",header=None,delimiter='\t',names = ['Tiempos no Contributivos','Tiempos Contributivos', 'Tiempos Productivos'])
y_pos = np.arange(len(df.columns))
bars = df.sum(axis=0)

plt.bar(y_pos, bars, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, df.columns)
plt.ylabel("Tiempo(segundos)", fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel(" ", fontsize=12)
plt.title('Tiempo')

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Tried it but i had 2 issues.
1. Is the dfgroup defined as mine?
2. Tried it with my dfgroup, but still got the same error.

Comment: Just send me the file you're using via pastebin.com . And include all relevant plotting code in another pastebin.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3CqhWp8v This is the data
https://pastebin.com/aTadcCnL This is the code. Just change the source from where you import the data

Comment: @JuanPabloMejiaRuiz Updated.

Comment: Looks fantastic, but still got an issue. The file you are loading is still the .txt file. I tried it with my csv file and it got issues with the numbers it was reading

Comment: Im assuming the mistake is in that the code has problems reading the floats.

Comment: @JuanPabloMejiaRuiz My code works perfectly with that data provided and I have tested it with float values.  It doesn't matter if it's a .csv or .txt, it's reading it the exact same way (even tested changing the filename).  Add me on discord, Neil#6036 and send me the dataset.  Unfortunately, there is probably some small formatting detail that was missed.

Comment: Added you, im Kindle#2272